# How to Visualize Plotly Heatmap with Unstack Data

Tags: plotly, data-visualization, heatmap, data-analysis, plotly-python

I have this unstack dataset

| **day** | Thur | Fri | Sat | Sun |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **sex** |  |  |  |  |
| Male | 30 | 10 | 59 | 58 |
| Female | 32 | 9 | 28 | 18 |

Now how can I generate a heatmap plot with Plotly-Python where x value will be "day" and y value will be 'sex'.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of plotly-express' `px.imshow`

```py
import plotly_express as px
fig = px.imshow(df, color_continuous_scale='viridis')
fig.show()
```

Documentation: https://plotly.com/python/heatmaps/
List of colour maps: https://plotly.com/python/builtin-colorscales/